# How come the decoder gives a question mark?

Tags: i2c, oscilloscope, debugging, decoder

I'm using a scope to debug I2C (bit banging) by letting it capture the signal. I think that the output should be good, but the scope's decoder gives the following:

[image]

[image]

where there is a question mark after the second byte (I'm doing a multiple-byte read here). Does anyone know what that question mark might mean? Is it an error?

Thanks

-- EDIT 1

Add scaled out capture.

-- EDIT 2
 Having taken @Michael Karas's advice, I have now used another probe for Ch1. Indeed, the old probe was bad and under compensated! However, the decoder still gives a question mark.

[image]

Comment: What does the manual for your oscilloscope say about that question mark ?

Comment: You might want to see if that SCL waveform is a true depiction of the clock waveform. The low level tips are looking like they are getting dangerously close to the Vil limit of the I2C parts. Or it could be that you hooked up to that signal with a bad probe or without the probe GND hooked up properly. If the waveform is out of spec the scope decoder may decide to question the integrity of the bus protocol.

Comment: Another thing of concern here is the starting and ending levels of the SCL and SDA signals. When the I2C bus is inactive these lines are supposed to be pulled up to a high level. Your scope capture shows them both low before and after the transfer.  Something needs fixing here.

Comment: The whole waveform looks wrong. Are you sure it's I2C and not SPI? Another thing to note is that Rigol's decoders need a very high zoom level to work correctly. You'll have to capture at your depicted resolution and then zoom in to get usable results.

Comment: @MichaelKaras Sorry, I'm very new and don't quite understand how the low level tips of the clock might seem too low (?). Isn't Vil minimum 0V?

Comment: @NickAlexeev Unfortunately my manual doesn't say. :(

Comment: @MichaelKaras I'm actually trying to read 6 registers (of an ADXL345) and that screen depicts the reading of 2 (Y-axis). Between the reading of each pair, the SCL does stay low (is that alright?). However, before and after reading these 6, the SCL is pulled up to a high level. Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a close look at your waveform (now that it is clean with a good scope probe) it can be analyzed as shown below:

[image]

The most highly likely cause of the ? in the RIGOL I2C decoder is due to the I2C protocol getting all screwed up.

The first part of the protocol looks very reasonable. Later on it gets pretty messed up
and is surely what has led to the problem. I would recommend that a very careful look be taken at the following three areas. Once those are fixed things may start to improve.

Note A. The process of injecting the repeated start looks extremely suspect. It should not require the extra transitions on SDA to get the repeated start to work.

Note B. The transition zone of going from output of the read mode Slave Address to getting ready to read in data has suspect extra transitions on SDA.

Note C. The whole character of the clocking of SCL from this point on is very suspect. The timing of the clock should try to maintain the look of the previous three bytes of the clock timing. As a matter of fact if the previous three bytes of clocking could be tweaked to give closer to a 50% duty cycle it may be an improvement as well.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed analysis. With Note A, there're two high levels indeed, but one is ACK and one is START - so that should be reasonable, right? I send a high to SDA 10us after SCK. With Note B, the first high is, similarly, an ACK. And with Note C, I think SCK stays high for longer because of the time the master needs to read from the slave.

Answer (score 2):

The problem I wrote about in the comments under the question regarding the waveform signal integrity has to do with the SCL waveform shown as below:

[image]

To be able to ensure that you have reliable communications with the target device it will be necessary to make sure that your SCL driver is able to actually pull the SCL signal right down to GND level and not have it nearly a volt above the GND level. The slave device will not work correctly if the clock signal only pulls down to 1V.

The depicted SCL waveform could be caused by a scope probe that has not been properly frequency compensated.

It is also possible that you probed the signal without the GND lead of the scope connected near the signal source.

It is also possible that you have a truly bad scope probe or one with bad internal contacts in the connectors.

Since the waveform you show for the SDA looks so clean you may want to capture the waveforms with the probes swapped to see if the SCL displays properly with the other scope probe.

If the SCL waveform shown on the scope shot is truly an accurate depiction of the waveform on the board then some work needs to be done to correct the problem.

Comment: Thank you. It seems the probe is indeed under compensated and is bad - I should better return it! Now I'm using a new probe, but the decoder still gives a question mark.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the other issues, the question mark in the I2C decode line indicates a non-acknowledge (NACK).  The data line is left high after the last byte, in this case indicating that the master is finished accepting data.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the Rigol DS1054Z I2C decode question marks, the manual "DS1000Z Series Digital Oscilloscope" indicates on page 7-16:

*Error Information during [I2C] Decoding. When the ACK (ACKnowledge Character) is not met, “?” error marks as shown in the figure below will be displayed.*

The ? character thus simply indicates a NACK condition.

The use of the ? character is misleading in this context.